# Get a better yii2 rbac extension

Tags: yii2

Am using yii2 can i get an extension which has a physical interface for managing role based user access (R.B.A.C.).

```
I have tried using 
mdmsoft, dektrium, yii rbac plus but none has any explanation of how
```

to set up a physical one

Answer (score 1):

I have create a  physical interface for managing role based user simply using gii based on the tables provided by the defualt RBAC model provided by Yii2 and extendig the related action for inserting the proper value for assignments, roles, item and item_child.  ..

eg:  for create Assignments

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AuthAssignment();
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

        $auth->assign($auth->getRole($model->item_name), $model->user_id);
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'item_name' => $model->item_name, 'user_id' => $model->user_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and for create Item

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AuthItem();
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        switch ($model->type) {
            case AuthItem::TYPE_ROLE :   // 1 = TYPE_ROLE
                $role = $auth->createRole($model->name);
                $role->data         = $model->data;
                //$role->ruleName     = $model->rule_name;
                $role->description  = $model->description;
                //$role->type         = $model->type;
                $auth->add($role);
                break;                    
             case AuthItem::TYPE_PERMISSION :  // 2 = TYPE_PERMISSION
                $permission  = $auth->createPermission($model->name);
                $permission->data         = $model->data;
                //$permission->ruleName     = $model->rule_name;
                $permission->description  = $model->description;
                //$permission->type         = $model->type;
                $auth->add($permission);
                break;              
            default:
                break;
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->name]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```